# PHP URL redirect to specific page after login

Tags: php, mysql

beginner here with PHP.  Have a simple HTML form that calls this login.php:

```
<?php
require ('sql_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username=mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$password=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
if (!$_POST['uname'] | !$_POST['pass'])
 {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('You did not complete all of the required fields')
        window.location.href='htmlogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
     }
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$url=$row['defaultpage'];

header($url);


if($username !== null)
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully!  I will now direct you to $url')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
else{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
}
else{
}
?>
```

I've successfully tied into the database (mySQL), and added a column called 'defaultpage' which has a full URL.  My goal is that once a user logs in it will redirect them to the page i've specified in the database (via 'defaultpage')

Any help would be great.

Thank you all so much.

Comment: to redirect you can use `header('location:"www.yoururl.com"')`

Comment: Thanks, but "dumb" it down for me if you can... if I insert header('location:"www.yoururl.com"') in place of $URL, it does try to to the URL however, the URL will need to different depending on who logs in. Example, if Mike logs in, he'll need to be directed to www.mysite.com/mike

Answer (score 0):

$url should be something like "Location: http://www.yourFullURL.com", not just the URL

See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thanks, but "dumb" it down for me if you can... if I insert header('location:"www.yoururl.com"') in place of $URL, it does try to to the URL however, the URL will need to different depending on who logs in.  Example, if Mike logs in, he'll need to be directed to www.mysite.com/mike.

Comment: So if you have the url in your database, build a string like this: $url = "Location: " . $row['defaultpage'];

Comment: @Dre You've had two people spoon-feed you an answer, and one that directly links to the PHP documentation. Please take the time to do a little bit of research so you can understand ***why*** things need to be done, instead of just asking for the answer to be handed to you.

Comment: First, Chris - thanks for your willingness to help.  First words I mentioned was that I was a beginner, so thanks for your patience.  @Noah, my apologies to you as well - you could have just skipped my post all together, or attempted to help.  If you think I haven't been researching this for days then you're wrong.  I'm learning, just like we all are.

Chris, can I remove the header information then if i'm using my DB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Dre.  Does each user/login need to go to a different URL?  If so, keep doing what you're doing.  If not - that is, if successful logins always go to the same URL, then just hard-code your header into in your PHP.  No need to pull from the database for that.